# how to call css class using javascript? like in html once you call its classname it will automatically define what styles you want in div

Tags: javascript, css, class

ie. this is my class to be called in my javascript

```
<style>
   .chzn-select{
   }

</style>



                <select class="chzn-select" id="hidden_select" name="form_select" onchange="showSelect()"> 
                <option value="">Please Select Item</option>
                <option value="">Anything</option>
                </select>
```

i want to call this class="chzn-select" inside javascript, like document.getElementById().style.display = "none" or anyting styles to be in here using css class

```
<script>
   
enter code here
</script>
```

i want to call my class here and i dont know what will be my specific code to call my class="chzn-select";

Answer (score 0):

You can use a querySelector to select elements that have the class

> document.querySelector(".chzn-select").style.display = "none";